# Date to Day conversion R

Tags: r

Im trying to convert a Date column in a csv file to a new column `Day` using R. Day in terms of Monday Tuesday etc. Apparently yday gives day of the year. Any solution?

Comment: Check out the lubridate package in R.

Comment: Or you could use the `weekdays` function from base R, `weekdays(as.Date(g, format = "%m/%d/%y"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the format function with %a or %A

```
date <- as.Date("2017-05-20")
format(date, "%A")
[1] "Saturday"
format(date, "%a")
[1] "Sat"
```

If your original date is in the format "07/29/05" in the column A$Date you can call

```
strDays <- format(as.Date(A$Date, "%m/%d/%y"), "%A")
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on how can I add the column `Date` here. The format is 07/29/05. I guess I`ll need to convert it to 2005-07-29 format.

Comment: g=super$Date
strDatess <- format(g,format="%A")     This doesnt work.

Comment: I added an example for your format